# Rewriting URLs in Joomla! 1.0.13 Stable?

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the url's for a site based on Joomla! 1.0.13 Stable, I've never worked with joomla so I don't know much about it, how is it done? (The server is running, PHP Version 4.3.10) and I have renamed the htaccess.txt file .htaccess (although nothing has happend) and I can't find the Global Configuration link in my admin menu.

Comment: You should seriously consider updating the site to something a little more current. The 1.0.x series reached end of life well over a year ago and v1.7 is due out later this month. Your at risk of being hacked on something that old.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your url :

```
administrator/index.php?option=com_config
```

usually it's under site -> global configuration